# List of methods

Tags: python, list, methods

I wonder if its possible to create a list (or something) of methods.
For example, lets say I have a list

```
 lst = []
```

And I want to have specific methods e.g. `insert`, `remove` and stuff. And I would like to call those, randomly from the list, so that I can add something like `lst.add(3, 4)` but selecting the methods from the list of methods. Its silly, but its like I would like to do this: `lst.listofmethods[3]`

Possibly, the methods maybe should be stored in a dictionary instead?

Comment: What do you mean with *selecting that from the list*?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Whether a dictionary is better depends on your application, which you haven't described.  Didn't your research show you examples of methods handled as variables?

Comment: By "selecting that from the list" I meant "selecting the methods from the list of methods". I changed this now in the text to be clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there are two things that pop into mind:

- `dir(..)` returns you a list of the **names** of the methods. You can then use `getattr(..)` to get the attribute that listens to the given name. For example:

  ```
  >>> dir([])
  ['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'clear', 'copy', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
  ```

  So if you want to call `append` (index 34), you could using:

  ```
  getattr(lst,dir(lst)[34])('a')
  ```
- You can construct a list of methods like:

  ```
  listofmethods = [lst.append,lst.clear]
  ```

  and then call it with:

  ```
  listofmethod[1]()
  ```

  to call `clear()` on the list.

  of course you can also define a dictionary that works almost equivalent:

  ```
  dicofmethods = {'foo':lst.append,'bar':lst.clear}
  ```

  and call with:

  ```
  dicofmethods['foo'](42)
  ```

Answer (score 3):

You can store functions into dictionary as well.

```
>>> def foo():
...     print("foo")
... 
>>> def bar():
...     print("bar")
... 
>>> 
>>> foobar = {"foo": foo, "bar" : bar}
>>> foobar["foo"]()
foo
>>> foobar["bar"]()
bar
>>> foobar["bar"]
<function bar at 0x7f0561c6eae8>
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can store functions in a list, like this:

```
def f ():
    print ('f')

def g ():
    print ('g')

aList = [f, g]

for aFunction in aList:
    aFunction ()
```